# Google silentSignIn from non-activity

Tags: android

I am working on an app where I use googles sign-in api.

I am wondering in though; how do you use this silent sign-in if for instance you want to refresh the google-token from a controller class (not an activity)?

The docs gives an example like this:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

This works fine from an activity, but I want to be able to refresh the sign-in token in the background from a non-activity, and without starting one.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
Context ctx = ....//e.g., from Service use this.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(ctx)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
```